# Represent effectiveness percentage when target is zero

Tags: statistics

How can I represent with a percentage when I have an indicator which is target is zero?

I mean for example, talking about medical incidents, in my company the month target is obviously zero incidents,

So, how can I say how much effectiveness we were back in January if we have 5 incidents?

How can I represent the integer 5 in terms of percentage if my target of incidents is zero?, I mean we were 90% effective, 85%? since division by zero is not possible to make a rule of three I was wondering if there is a another way to do this.

Comment: maybe you could do some type of historical effectiveness. So for example find the average number of incidents per month over some period of years and compare to this.

Answer (score 0):

You are right you can't say you are some percentage above target when the target is zero. You can talk of percentage increase or decrease compared to another month, or the average of last year.